# set not expected at this time, batch?

Tags: batch-file

OK so I have this little game I am writing on this Windows XP computer in batch. I get "set was not expected at this time" when I run the following code(sorry it's real long I just haven't made it smaller yet. *NOTE* I didn't ask for you to make my code smaller, so please DO NOT do it):

```
    @echo off 
    set str=0
    set int=0
    set agi=0
    set dex=0
    goto chrselect

    :chrselect
    cls
    echo Character select!
    echo.
    echo 1) mage
    echo.
    echo 2) swords man
    echo.
    echo 3) archer
    set /p start=-
    if %start%==1 goto skillsetupm
    if %start%==2 goto skillsetups
    if %start%==3 goto skillsetupa 

    :skillsetupm
    set health=50
    set mana=100
    set str=3
    set int=6
    set agi=5
    set dex=4 
    set chr=m1
    goto skillsee

    :skillsetups
    set health=100
    set mana=50
    set str=6
    set int=4
    set agi=3
    set dex=5
    set chr=s1
    goto skillsee

    :skillsetupa
    set health=75
    set mana=75
    set str=3
    set int=4
    set agi=6
    set dex=5
    set chr=a1
    goto skillsee 

    :skillsee
    cls
    echo Skills as is: 
    echo.
    echo Strength: %str%
    echo Intelligence: %int%
    echo Agility: %agi%
    echo Dexterity: %dex%
    echo.
    echo 1) Choose new character
    echo.
    echo 2) Continue to see how stats influence combat!
    set /p start=-
    if %start%==1 goto chrselect
    if %start%==2 goto skillc

    :skillc
    set /a handattk=3+%str%
    set /a magicattk=2+%str%+%dex% 
    set /a block=%agility%+%dex%
    set /a blockchnc=%block%*5
    set /a bowattk=3+%str%+%dex%
    set /a swrdattk=4+%str%+%dex%
    set /a slowchnc=%str%*4
    if %chr%==m1 goto skillcinf
    if %chr%==s1 goto skillcinf
    if %chr%==a1 goto skillcinf

    :skillcinf
    cls
    echo Skill stuff!
    echo.
    echo Hand attack: %handattk%
    echo.
    echo Block chance: %blockchnc% %
    echo.
    echo Slow chance: %slowchnc% %
    echo.
    if %chr%==m1 echo Magic attack: %magicattk%
    if %chr%==s1 echo Sword attack: %swrdattk%
    if %chr%==a1 echo Bow attack: %bowattk%
    echo.
    echo 1) Choose new character(last chance)
    echo.
    echo 2) Start game
    set /p start=-
    if %start%==1 goto chrselect
    if %start%==2 goto menue

    :menue
    cls
    set bossh=500
    set exp=0
    set playcount=0
    echo                          Health:///%health%///
    echo                          Mana:////%mana%////
    echo                          Experience:////%exp%///// 
    echo                          Play count: %playcount%
    echo Battle?(y/n) 
    set /p start=-
    if %start%==y goto battle
    if %start%==n goto menue

    :battle 
    set /a playcount=%playcount%+1
    cls
    echo                          Health:///%health%///
    echo                          Mana:////%mana%////
    echo                          Experience:////%exp%///// 
    echo                          Play count: %playcount%  
    echo Attack Dragon(Health:%bossh%) with?
    echo.
    echo 1-Hand(%handattk% damage)
    echo.
    echo 2-Block(%blockchnc% % chance of blocking)
    echo.
    if %chr%==m1 echo 3-Magic attack(%magicattk% damage)
    if %chr%==s1 echo 3-Sword Attack(%swrdattack% damage)
    if %chr%==a1 echo 3-Bow Attack (%bowattk% damage)
    set /p start=-
    pause >nul
    if %start%==1 set /a bossh=%bossh%-%handattk%
    if %start%==2 set /a blockrandm=%random% %%100
    goto battle2
    if %start%==3 goto spclattk

    :spclattk
    cls
    if %chr%==m1 set /a bossh=%bossh%-%magicattk%%
    if %chr%==s1 set /a bossh=%bossh%-%swrdattk%
    if %chr%==a1 set /a bossh=%bossh%-%bowattk%
    goto battle2

    :battle2
    if %bossh% leq 0 goto win
    set /a bossd=%random% %%5 
    if %blockrandm%==%blockchnc% set bossd=0
    set /a health=%health%-%bossd%
    cls
    echo                          Health:///%health%///
    echo                          Mana:////%mana%////
    echo                          Experience:////%exp%///// 
    echo                          Play count: %playcount% 
    echo Attack Dragon(Health:%bossh%) with?
    echo.
    echo 1-Hand(%handattk% damage)
    echo.
    echo 2-Block(%blockchnc% % chance of blocking)
    echo.
    if %chr%==m1 echo 3-Magic attack(%magicattk% damage)
    if %chr%==s1 echo 3-Sword Attack(%swrdattack% damage)
    if %chr%==a1 echo 3-Bow Attack (%bowattk% damage)
    set /p start=-
    if %start%==1 set /a bossh=%bossh%-%handattk%
    if %start%==2 set /a blockrandm=%random% %%100
    if %start%==3 goto battleattk
    goto battle2
```

Anytime I get to the :battle screen and press an option I get set was not expected at this time.

Comment: That's some dedication there...

Comment: You ask us not to make your code smaller but at the same time you do *nothing at all* to make sure you only include the relevant portions of your code, making everyone of us read a wall of code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 @Joey, you seem to be taking it personally :-)

Comment: Your `set /a` statements might become easier to read if you got rid of the `%`s: `set /a handattk=3+%str%` -> `set /a handattk=3+str`, `set /a magicattk=2+%str%+%dex%` -> `set /a magicattk=2+str+dex` and so on (except you can't do the same for system variables, like `%random%`). And assignments like `set /a playcount=%playcount%+1` can be simplified even further: `set /a playcount=+1`.

Comment: Oops, the last bit was supposed to be `set /a playcount+=1`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `%blockrandm%` isn't initialised when you get to `:battle2` so the comparison in line 148 reads

```
if ==0 set bossd=0
```

which obviously is invalid syntax. You can avoid it by quoting both sides of the comparison (which is a *great* idea in practically all cases when writing such code).

For future reference: Remove the `echo off` and you at least see what line is responsible and often also why it fails.

Comment: +1, Or in this case, since the OP new approximately at what point the error occured, the OP could have added `SET ECHO ON` immediately after the `:battle` label. No need to echo lines that are known to work.

Comment: Right, although when exiting a batch via a syntax error you see the offending line just above your prompt. It's just a little more noise beforehand, but you just have to go through three or four prompts here until that happens.